# Update Paypal IPN message details

Tags: paypal-ipn

Is there a way to update the variable data that was sent to paypal?

Given this scenario, a customer purchases an item with code A, then code B is introduced that now logs users id and other information. But all customers who purchased using code A will not be correctly identified by code B.

I can see the IPN message detail in the IPN history, but I just wished I could type into that box and manually update/correct a few of the variables.

Is there  a way to do this, or a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the customer's recurring payment profile using another API. I don't know what the point of amending, at PayPal, an IPN message that has already been sent to you is, but you can't do it, and you don't want to do it. You would be lying to yoursef about what they have sent you, and perpetrating a fraud against PayPal as well. All you have to do is adjust what happened at your end.

Comment: well my issue was that blank "custom" fields was sent over and later fixed. I wanted to dig into the IPN messages and add in the customers ID into that "custom" field.

Comment: Why? The IPN History is PayPal's record of *what was actually sent.* What good is changing that going to do you, even if it was possible, ethical, legal, etc.?

Comment: i was asking because to fix the issue at this point would be to make the customer cancel their subscription and sign up again so that the new code would correctly send information to the IPN.

Comment: @Eli No. That's what the first sentence in my answer is about. You can fix the recurring payment profile using the API.